# ¿Cómo funciona el método .append de javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación simple para cargar productos, la estoy haciendo con jquery y bootstrap, necesito saber cómo puedo una vez que ya calcule el valor de un producto, mostrarlo en forma de tabla, estoy haciéndolo con la función `.append` pero todavía no puedo terminar de entenderla. Adjunto el código y una imagen de cómo debería quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var especie;
var cantidad;
var precio;
var total;

function suma(){
 especie = document.getElementById('especie').value;
 cantidad = document.getElementById('cant').value;
 precio = document.getElementById('compra').value;
 total = cantidad*precio;
   document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;
  
  $("#sum").click(function(){
  $(".cuadro").append(
    '<div class=col>Especie</div>'
     '<div class=col>Hola</div>'
   
    );

});




};
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.container{
 position:fixed;
 height: 400px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

.ct1{
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.ct2{
 padding: 0 5px;
}

.cuadro{
 height: 400px;
 width: 700px;
 border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Movizen Bootstrap</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container bg-primary">
    <div class="row text-white ct1">
      <div class="col">Especie</div>
      <div class="col">Cantidad</div>
      <div class="col">Precio($)</div>
      <div class="col">Total($)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ct2">
     <input type="text" id="especie" placeholder="Especie">
     <input type="text" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad">
     <input type="text" id="compra" placeholder="Precio compra">
     <input type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Total" disabled>
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" placeholder="Total" onclick="suma()" id="sum" value="+" />
    </div>
    <div class="row cuadro">
     
    </div>
 </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: saludos bro, eso está en la documentación oficial, ¡a leer! https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en el append estás agregando datos con comillas 2 veces ('<div class=col>Especie</div>'  '<div class=col>Hola</div>'), coloca todo dentro de las mismas comillas.